# A TV series where the characters travel through portals to alternative dimensions

Tags: story-identification, soft-sci-fi

Me and my mate were talking about TV shows we watched, growing up, and we both have vague memory of the same show.

In the show, the characters would jump through portals, and pop out in weird alternate universes. My mate specifically remembers a weird 'Suburbia'.

We can both remember an evil lobster, but they may have been a main antagonist, or in a single episode.

We live in Australia, but can not remember the network, nor country of origin.

I watched this when I was a kid, so either 6am-9am or 3pm-10pm EST. My mate remembers watching it at night. We don't really have a date, so 1995-2010 it was airing on australian free-to-air.

We don't remember any markings akin to Star Wars or Star Trek, but we can not rule it out.

Reading through the premise, and watching a youtube video, "Sliders" does remind us of the series, but we are still not 100% sure this is it.

It is possible that I am remembering elements from Parralax, regardless of whether this is the actual series we both remember. I definetly use to watch Parralax, as a kid, but it does not fit the time frame my friend remembers. Parralax would air after school, and he remembers the show airing at night time.

The deciding factor would definetly be those 'antagonist lobsters'.

Comment: Can you provide more details, including the approximate years when you watched this? Was the show live action or animated? Did it feature characters with markings on their forehead (Stargate or Star Trek)? Did the intro show a whole long series of copies of Earth next to each other (Sliders)?

Comment: Did you try to Google this, perhaps look through https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_fiction_employing_parallel_universes ?

Comment: Hmmmm way before sliders there WAS another such series that I saw once (not sure though what it was) but it had a 60s look to it. sure that it is not such an old one?

Comment: Is it [Jumper](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jumper_(2008_film))?

Comment: Sliders changed cast and focus considerably in its later seasons, so it's possible it's still that show, even though the pilot didn't match what you remembered.

Comment: @Thomas - [The Time Tunnel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Time_Tunnel)? [Quantum Leap](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantum_Leap)?

Comment: could be both. only rememberd that there was somthing like the described

Comment: Was the lobster an actual lobster, or was it a lobster-like humanoid?

Comment: @user2989297, we remember lobster in terms of the rough size and appearance

Comment: BCdotWEB, we looked there before I posted.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Maybe [Parallax](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parallax_%28TV_series%29), which aired in Australia in 2004.

It involves characters going through a portal to jump to various parallel universes. Wikipedia mentions a "hippie world", a "techno world", a "forest world", and others.

I can't find anything about a lobster alien, but there is a weird alien shown in the intro at about 11 seconds in.

Comment: I havean odd feeling that this is it, or some of what I am remembering has come from this, as I definetly remember this show. Will do more research, myself.

Comment: Apologies for any confusion, but I am confident the 'antagonist lobster' I remember was actually the "Welkin", crossed with the disadvantage of only having a very vague recollection

Answer (score 13):

It's possible that you are thinking of [*Stargate SG-1*](http://stargate.mgm.com/view/series/1/).

The show follows a team of scientists and military officers that use advanced alien technoloy called a Stargate, which opens a stable wormhole between two distant gates. You use these gates to planet-hop.

[image]

The early episodes had a very strongly Egyptian feel to them -- the primary "bad" aliens were supposedly the influence behind Egyptian mythology -- but they also travelled to a lot of other varied planets and met lots of cultures.

There was a broadly lobster-like creature called a Reetu (or Re'tu) that appeared a couple of times. It's not really evil, though I believe their first appearance a "rebel faction" would have seemed like the antagonists. Here's a shot of a bunch of them:

[image]

Comment: +1. A stargate definitely fits with the "portal" (in-universe it's a wormhole to distant planets, but they don't spell that out every time). The Reetou (sources differ on spelling) appeared in several episodes, and are large, non-humanoid insect-like creatures. Also, they're normally invisible and usually only seen on-screen for no more than a few seconds in dark shots, and so could easily be seen as "huge lobster antagonist". Whether this is the OP's show or not, it sure seems like a decent fit. (I've watched all ten seasons three times now, and can't see a reason why *not*, if that helps).

Comment: Better image of Reetou - http://stargate.wikia.com/wiki/Reetou

Comment: Definetly not stargate. I thought I had made it obvious that we were aware of stargate, and besides, stargate still regularly airs on TV.

Comment: Your question doesn't say anything about Stargate. It's been of the air for a long time in the US, I don't even think there's any channel playing repeats of it. I get that it's the wrong answer but bad enough for a -1?

Comment: @type_outcast: Minor correction: While the Reetou were mentioned several times, they only ever appeared once.

Answer (score 10):

Adding to [phantom42's answer](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/112974/58395), I did some work on the website for Parallax way back in 2004, and have a backup of some of the images.

The purple lobster-like creature seems to be a Krellick:

[image]

[image]

The flying purple creature from the promo video is a Welkin:

[image]

[image]

There's a whole heap of Krellicks in this video, starting about 11 minutes in:

Comment: Why is everyone in that video holding nerf guns?

Comment: cuz it's Australia, they only use guns to distract you while they get their knives.

Comment: @MasonWheeler I seem to remember it having something to do with being able to kill the Krellicks by spraying them with water - and so they carried water pistols. Found a full run-down of each episode at http://www.australiantelevision.net/parallax/episodes.html, and looks like that's the case :)

Answer (score 3):

Could it be the TV series  [Sliders](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sliders)

Comment: That's the first thing that came to my mind

Comment: The question already says they don't think it's Sliders. If you think it is, you'll need to provide details that align with what's in the question, rather than just name dropping the show.

Comment: This came to my mind as well, but I'm with @ChrisHayes on this: you posted this answer hours after the OP's edit that specifically excluded Sliders. I watched it when it first aired, and also tried to find any evidence of lobster creatures or anything even close, but could not. (Top image search results came back to this question, others were food shots of lobster sliders. Mmm.) I remember an episode with dinosaurs, but they didn't encounter non-humanoids much, as the realities were pretty similar to their own. Do you know any details that might help? Maybe I'm forgetting an episode.

Comment: I in no way excluded Sliders. As I say in my question, it rings bells, but we cant say 100% yet. The lobster antagonist would be the deciding role

Comment: This is actually the only suggestion we can both agree on, to an extent

Answer (score 3):

I too had wondered for ages about this show. I originally watched it in Cuba. I remembered they wore suits and created portals with their hands.

After searching online for hours I found it! I hope it's the same show you were looking for. It's called ***[Spellbinder](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spellbinder_(TV_series))***!

> A group of teenagers go on a school camp in the Blue Mountains in Australia. While at the camp, Paul Reynolds accidentally goes into a parallel universe. This other world is inhabited by a more hierarchic and technologically different society, ruled by a group of people known as Spellbinders. Paul meets a girl there named Riana, and they become friends.
>
> The Spellbinders have discovered the power to create and manipulate static electricity. They fly in gigantic copper-coloured machines that utilise large rotating orange crystals, presumably creating some form of magnetic levitation. The Spellbinders often use their power for good, but some abuse this power and use their discoveries for malevolence. One such malevolent Spellbinder is Ashka, who often manages to hide her true nature. Common people are often "banished" for their misdeeds, and sometimes Spellbinders are banished, also, if they are proven to have done wrong.
>
> There is tension from Paul's forays into the land of the Spellbinders and his attempts to return to his own universe, and also from conversations Paul has with his friends across the barrier between the two universes. Paul and Riana's escapes also add tension, as do the interactions between Spellbinders.
>
> <sub>[Spellbinder (TV Series): Synopsis @ Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spellbinder_(TV_series)#Synopsis)</sub>

Comment: It is not, as I have already found the one I was looking for, but that could make your answer even more valuable, as your suggestion sounds really cool. Could you add more to your answer? A plot synopsis copy pasted and referenced from IMDB, or a trailer from youtube, perhaps? Look at the accepted answer and use it as a guide.

Comment: @Gnemlock I removed the last couple of paragraphs which look like plot spoilers. The rest of the quote should be enough to describe the setup of the story so that people can tell what it's about and how closely it fits the description in the OP.

Comment: @Gnemlock: That was a bit sloppy of me.