# Kid's fantasy TV show/movie from 30+ years ago where kids go under their duvet which leads to magical tunnels

Tags: story-identification, tv

I don't know if it's a vivid dream or an actual TV show or film but I think kids were able to go under their duvet in their beds and it led to some magical tunnels *also made out of duvets* that led to other times/places/dimensions.

I remember the tunnels were small so had to be crawled through, and some and the end of the tunnels were like portals that you could see the other worlds through and access them from! I think maybe one portal was an Egypt or desert thing.

The kids were white, both boys and girls and aged approximately 9 to 13. I think it was a U.K. T.V. show, but it may have been American.

Comment: Not a duvet but rather whole-beds, and a lot of the other details don't really fit so I don't feel comfortable putting it as a real answer, but any chance it could be the Fred Savage/Howie Mandel movie Little Monsters?

Comment: Cartoon or live action?

Comment: It puts me in mind of [Jamie and the Magic Torch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jamie_and_the_Magic_Torch)

Comment: I accidentally stumbled on this question which "might" be related: https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/226019/cartoon-series-kids-disappearing-under-bed-into-rectangular-blue-portals

Comment: It also barely reminded me of this animated series, although it's not old enough (not 30+ years ago): https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/King_(2003_TV_series)

Comment: Another possibly related question: https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/112966/a-tv-series-where-the-characters-travel-through-portals-to-alternative-dimension

Comment: I’ve been trying to remember what it was called for years. I always thought it was “Finders Keepers” but that was a different show. I vaguely remember the title sequence of a kid flying? I could be confusing with other shows at the time, though. I definitely remember the kid(s) going under the duvet and some weird world made of bedsheets. And I think there was a pit?
Anyway, it’s not "Little Monsters with Fred Savage" and it’s not animated.